# How to update sbt

Tags: updates

At the present time, you might get this on auto-update, because the recent sbt packages are not authenticated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To install the latest version of the sbt .deb package open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl gnupg -yqq
echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt_old.list
curl -sL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823" | sudo -H gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/scalasbt-release.gpg --import
sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/scalasbt-release.gpg
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sbt
```

Once sbt is installed, you’ll be able to manage/update the package after you updated its package cache. You should also be able to see the added repository at the bottom of the list in *Software & Updates* -> *Other Software*.

**Reference:** 
• [sbt Reference Manual - Installing sbt on Linux](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html)

Comment: updated instructions are here https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I manually downloaded & installed the latest version deb file from http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/, and disabled that source url in ubuntu updates, as I am not aware how to tell it to suffice with an unautheticated source on each auto-update, nor do I think that would be a very good idea. Indeed that package updates `/usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/bin/` where my previous version of sbt resided.

Some people suggested circumventing the need by using an alternative runner: https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras, haven't tried.